# What if multiple threads epoll wait on the same socket?

Tags: linux, multithreading, epoll

What if multiple threads epoll wait on the same socket? 
In my own experiment, it showed that only one thread can invoke epoll_wait successfully, the other threads show Invalid arguments error. Could someone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call epoll_wait concurrently on multiple threads for the same epoll_fd.

```
  event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLONESHOT;
```

http://www.csh.rit.edu/~rossdylan/presentations/EpollMT/

Answer (score 0):

You can epoll_wait concurrently on multiple threads for the same fd. But epoll doesn't handle thread synchronization like IOCP. It is possible that all the threads come out of epoll_wait call when an event occurs on one of the sockets. Usually only one thread is enough to wait on epoll_wait. You can then give the task of receiving or sending data to other threads from the epoll_wait thread (polling thread).